# Understand the usage of strand without locking

Tags: boost, boost-asio, boost-beast, boost-beast-websocket

Reference:
[websocket_client_async_ssl.cpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async-ssl/websocket_client_async_ssl.cpp)
[strands](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html)

**Question 1**> Here is my understanding:

> Given a few async operations bound with the same strand, the strand
> will guarantee that all associated async operations will be executed
> as a strictly sequential invocation.

Does this mean that all above async operations will be executed by a same thread?
Or it just says that at any time, only one asyn operation will be executed by any available thread?

**Question 2**> The `boost::asio::make_strand` function creates a strand object for an executor or execution context.

```
session(net::io_context& ioc, ssl::context& ctx)
    : resolver_(net::make_strand(ioc))
    , ws_(net::make_strand(ioc), ctx)
```

Here, `resolver_` and `ws_` have its own strand, but I have problems to understand how each strand applies to what asyn operations.

For example, in the following aysnc and handler, which functions(i.e aysnc or handler) are bound to the same strand and will not run simultaneously.

```
run
  =>resolver_.async_resolve -->session::on_resolve 
    =>beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).async_connect -->session::on_connect
      =>ws_.next_layer().async_handshake --> session::on_ssl_handshake
        =>ws_.async_handshake --> session::on_handshake
```

async ================================= handler

**Question 3**> How can we retrieve the strand from executor?
Is there any difference between these two?

[get_associated_executor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/get_associated_executor.html)
[get_executor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/get_executor.html)

> io_context::get_executor: Obtains the executor associated with the
> io_context.
>
> get_associated_executor: Helper function to obtain an object's
> associated executor.

**Question 4**> Is it correct that I use the following method to bind `deadline_timer` to `io_context` to prevent race condition?

All other parts of the code is same as the example of websocket_client_async_ssl.cpp.

```
session(net::io_context& ioc, ssl::context& ctx)
    : resolver_(net::make_strand(ioc))
    , ws_(net::make_strand(ioc), ctx),
    d_timer_(ws_.get_executor())
{     }

void on_heartbeat_write( beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
  d_timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
  d_timer_.async_wait(beast::bind_front_handler( &session::on_heartbeat, shared_from_this()));
}

void on_heartbeat(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
    ws_.async_write( net::buffer(text_ping_), beast::bind_front_handler( &session::on_heartbeat_write, shared_from_this()));
}

void on_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
{
    d_timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
    d_timer_.async_wait(beast::bind_front_handler( &session::on_heartbeat, shared_from_this()));
    ws_.async_write(net::buffer(text_), beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_write, shared_from_this()));
}
```

Note:
I used `d_timer_(ws_.get_executor())` to init `deadline_timer` and hoped that it will make sure they don't write or read the websocket at the same time.
Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: In the interest of quality Q&A it's nicer if you can ask fewer questions per post. Your numbering is rather generous, I think I saw at least 7 questions. In this case they are rather related, so I indulged, but perhaps if you had just asked a single question, you might have gotten the same information, perhaps more coherently. I'm not sure it will work, but maybe worth a try.

Comment: Sorry about this. I will limit one question per post in in future. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Question 1

> Does this mean that all above async operations will be executed by a same thread? Or it just says that at any time, only one async operation will be executed by any available thread?

The latter.

#### Question 2

> Here, resolver_ and ws_ have its own strand,

Let me interject that I think that's unnecessarily confusing in the example. They could (should, conceptually) have used the same strand, but I guess they didn't want to go through the trouble of storing a strand. I'd probably have written:

```
explicit session(net::io_context& ioc, ssl::context& ctx)
    : resolver_(net::make_strand(ioc))
    , ws_(resolver_.get_executor(), ctx) {}
```

The initiation functions are called **where you decide**. The completion handlers are `dispatch`-ed on the executor that belongs to the IO object that you call the operation on, **unless** the completion handler is bound to a different executor (e.g. using `bind_executor`, see `get_associated_exectutor`). In by far the most circumstances in modern Asio, you will *not* bind handlers, instead "binding IO objects" to the proper executors. This makes it less typing, and much harder to forget.

So in effect, all the async-initiations in the chain **except** for the one in `run()` are all on a strand, because the IO objects are tied to strand executors.

**You** have to keep in mind to dispatch on a strand when some **outside** user calls into your classes (e.g. often to `stop`). It is a good idea therefore to develop a convention. I'd personally make all the "unsafe" methods and members `private:`, so I will often have pairs like:

```
  public:
    void stop() {
        dispatch(strand_, [self=shared_from_this()] { self->do_stop(); });
    }

  private:
    void do_stop() {
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).cancel();
    }
```

> ***Side Note***:
>
> In this particular example, there is only one (main) thread running/polling the io service, so the whole point is moot. But as I explained recently ([Does mulithreaded http processing with boost asio require strands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71459523/does-mulithreaded-http-processing-with-boost-asio-require-strands/71459649#71459649)), the examples are here to show some common patterns that allow one to do "real life" work as well

### Bonus: Handler Tracking

Let's use `BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING` to get some insight.¹ Running a sample session shows something like

[image]

If you squint a little, you can see that all the strand executors are the same:

```
0*1|resolver@0x559785a03b68.async_resolve
1*2|strand_executor@0x559785a02c50.execute
2*3|socket@0x559785a05770.async_connect
3*4|strand_executor@0x559785a02c50.execute
4*5|socket@0x559785a05770.async_send
5*6|strand_executor@0x559785a02c50.execute
6*7|socket@0x559785a05770.async_receive
7*8|strand_executor@0x559785a02c50.execute
8*9|socket@0x559785a05770.async_send
9*10|strand_executor@0x559785a02c50.execute
10*11|socket@0x559785a05770.async_receive
11*12|strand_executor@0x559785a02c50.execute
12*13|deadline_timer@0x559785a05958.async_wait
12*14|socket@0x559785a05770.async_send
14*15|strand_executor@0x559785a02c50.execute
15*16|socket@0x559785a05770.async_receive
16*17|strand_executor@0x559785a02c50.execute
17*18|socket@0x559785a05770.async_send
13*19|strand_executor@0x559785a02c50.execute
18*20|strand_executor@0x559785a02c50.execute
20*21|socket@0x559785a05770.async_receive
21*22|strand_executor@0x559785a02c50.execute
22*23|deadline_timer@0x559785a05958.async_wait
22*24|socket@0x559785a05770.async_send
24*25|strand_executor@0x559785a02c50.execute
25*26|socket@0x559785a05770.async_receive
26*27|strand_executor@0x559785a02c50.execute
23*28|strand_executor@0x559785a02c50.execute
```

### Question 3

> How can we retrieve the strand from executor?

You don't[*]. However `make_strand(s)` returns an equivalent strand if `s` is already a strand.

[*] By default, Asio's IO objects use the type-erased executor (`asio::executor` or `asio::any_io_executor` depending on version). So technically you **could** ask it about its `target_type()` and, after comparing the type id to some expected types use something like `target<net::strand<net::io_context::executor_type>>()` to access the original, but there's really no use. You don't want to be inspecting the implementation details. Just honour the handlers (by dispatching them on their associated executors like Asio does).

> Is there any difference between these two? get_associated_executor get_executor

`get_executor` gets an owned executor from an IO object. It is a member function.

`asio::get_associated_executor` gets associated executors from handler objects. You will observe that `get_associated_executor(ws_)` doesn't compile (although some IO objects may [satisfy the criteria](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html#:%7E:text=The%20executor%20may%20be%20customised%20for%20a%20particular%20handler%20type%20by%20specifying%20a%20nested%20type%20executor_type%20and%20member%20function%20get_executor()) to allow it to work).

### Question 4

> Is it correct that I use the following method to bind deadline_timer to io_context

You will notice that you did the same as I already mentioned above to tie the timer IO object to the same strand executor. So, kudos.

> to prevent race condition?

You don't prevent race conditions here. You prevent *data races*. That is because in `on_heartbeat` you **access** the `ws_` object which is an instance of a class that is NOT threadsafe. In effect, you're sharing access to non-threadsafe resources, and you need to *serialize* access, hence you want to be on the strand that all other accesses are also on.

> Note: [...] and hoped that it will make sure they don't write or read the websocket at the same time. Is this the right way to do it?

Yes this is a good start, but it is not enough.

Firstly, you **can** write or read at the same time, as long as

- write operations don't overlap
- read operations don't overlap
- accesses to the IO object are safely serialized.

In particular, your `on_heartbeat` might be safely serialized so you don't have a data race on calling the `async_write` initiation function. However, you need more checks to know whether a write operation is already (still) in progress. One way to achieve that is to have a queue with outgoing messages. If you have strict heartbeat requirements and high load, you might need a priority-queue here.

---

¹ I simplified the example by replacing the stream type with the Asio native `ssl::stream<tcp::socket>`. This means we don't get all the internal timers that deal with `tcp_stream` expirations. See https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/sPRYh6Xbwz/